# User is logged out when refreshing page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-login

I am having issues with a Wordpress members site. The install is multisite with subdomains.

I require the user to be logged in to view all pages of the subdomain site. To do this I have opted against any functions and placed `<?php wp_login_form(); ?>` within the `page-template` as shown here...

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
get_header(); ?>
   <div class="page-content-wrapper ">
   </div>
<?php get_footer();?>

<?php } else {?>
<?php get_header('login'); ?>
<?php wp_login_form(); ?>
<?php get_footer('login');?>
<?php }?>
```

This works a charm - when a `is_user_logged_in()` they get the page and when not they get `wp_login_form();`. My issue arises when leaving this page. The user is logged out and upon returning to the page has to login again as shown here.

[image: Login error]

This also happens when I add `if ( is_user_logged_in() )` to other pages.

I have also tried a redirect to `wp-login.php` when a user is required to login but this does the just loops back to `wp-login.php` which suggests to me that I am having a cookie issue as the login credentials logged.

I have noticed that before login the cookies are shown as shown

[image: Cookies before login]

and after login they show as shown

[image: Cookies after login]

Upon revisiting the page that requires login the cookies revert to the original. However, user credentials are never stored.

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE** 
It appears that if I first log into `wp-admin` I can visit the page and the user information is displayed. If I leave the page the user is logged out and a login is required.

Comment: Could it be because my main site is HTTPS and the Subdomains are HTTP and the cookie is not able to authenticate a login session?

Comment: This was not the issue.

Comment: is there a way we can have a link to the site and login credential to test (just create one for test)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155161/discussion-between-darren-mathers-and-temani-afif).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a code issue in your footer.php line 38 :

```
<a role="button" href="<?php wp_logout(); ?> "
```

you are using **wp_logout()** that makes user logout when they visit the front-end of the site. you need to replace it by this :

```
<a role="button" href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(); ?> ">
```

this one is good as it will put the link in order to enable user to logout when clicking.